# Calling callback method with same parameters at run time

Tags: javascript

This is my code:

```
function someOuter() {
    const x = 10;
    const y = 20;
    myMethod.done((x, y) => {
        return x + y;
    });
}
```

How to define `myMethod.done`, so that it can call the callback method passed into it with the same arguments at run time?

```
const myMethod = {
    done: (callback) => {
        // How to call callback, to read params correctly and then call callback();
    },
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You have [shadowed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable_shadowing) the `x` and `y` variables.

The `x` and `y` that are declared as the function parameters are different to the `x` and `y` defined as `const`s.

[Don't do that](https://eslint.org/docs/latest/rules/no-shadow).

If you *never care* about `done` being able to pass values into the function (which would make it an odd callback function) then just don't shadow them.

```js
function someOuter() {
    const x = 10;
    const y = 20;
    myMethod.done(() => {
        return x + y;
    });
}
```

If you *sometimes* care then you need to determine what conditions you want to care under.

For example:

```js
function someOuter() {
    const x = 10;
    const y = 20;
    myMethod.done((a, b) => {
        const first = a ?? x;
        const second = b ?? y;
        console.log({x, y, a, b, first, second});
        return first + second;
    });
}


const myMethod = {
    done: (cb) => {
        console.log('result', cb(3));
    },
}

someOuter();
```